# How can we be sure that optimum exists in Robust Sparse PCA?

Tags: pca, optimization, robust

I am reading the paper about [Robust Sparse Principal Component Analysis](http://www.statistik.tuwien.ac.at/forschung/SM/SM-2011-2complete.pdf). the method uses projection pursuit, and the problem boils down to optimisation of the following function:

$$
\bar{a}_j = \underset{\|a\| = 1, a\perp \tilde{a}_1, \ldots, a\perp \tilde{a}_{j-1}}{\arg\max} V(a^tx_1, \ldots, a^tx_n) - \lambda_j\|a\|_1
$$

Where $V$ - is some robust measure of scale, in general case can even be non-differentiable.
So, why we are so sure about existence of this optimum?

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms. What is "PCP"?

Comment: I think you are confusing existence of a maximum with the existence of a polynomial time algorithm that can find such a maximum.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, I'm just interested in theoretical existence of such a maximum.
I suppose, that if we can assume that V is continuous (not sure that we can), so as continuous function on compact set (unit sphere), it reaches it's maximum on this set.

Comment: In this case, I don't see what you are after. Why do you think the function should be smooth in order to have a maximum (I am assuming you mean a finite maximum)? There is a set of parameters where this function will attain the highest value no matter what (yes there may be several maximum). If it is not continuous then the neighbor points are not guaranteed to be close to the maximum.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, I was just saying about the theorem, which states, that continuous function on compact set reaches  its supremum and infinum.
But in this case, I suppose continuity of function is not important. As it's not important for us to get the supremum. Just to get close to it would be OK.
To satisfy this condition it's enough for V to be bounded on unit circle. I assume that all considered robust estimators will satisfy this condition.